# Bash: expand parameters from variable. How?

Tags: bash, tar, expand

I want to expand tar parameter `--exclude` thru variable like:

```
set -x verbose
EXC=AAA,BBB
echo --exclude={$EXC} > /dev/null
```

Output:
`echo '--exclude={AAA,BBB}'`

But I expect:
`echo --exclude=AAA --exclude=BBB`

I tried different invocations, but nothing..
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `eval` to parse the line after substituting the variable.

```
eval "echo --exclude={$EXC}"
```

Comment: Here's the reason why: brace expansion occurs *before* variable expansion. `eval` passes the string through a 2nd round of expansions -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions