# Creating a full directory tree at once

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to create a complex directory structure in a bash script and was under the impression that the following would work:

```
mkdir -p tmpdir/{trunk/sources/{includes,docs},branches,tags}
```

Which would create:

```
          tmpdir
    ________|______
   |        |      |
branches   tags  trunk
                   |
                 sources
               ____|_____
              |          |
          includes     docs
```

However when I run my script I end up with:

```
tmpdir
   |
trunk
```

Is there a quick and easy way to do this or am I going to have to resort to

```
mkdir -p tmpdir/trunk/sources/includes
mkdir -p tmpdir/trunk/sources/docs
mkdir -p tmpdir/branches
mkdir -p tmpdir/tags
```

Comment: I just tested it and worked to me the way you desire. I am with `mkdir (GNU coreutils) 8.13`

Comment: I have a feeling this is the same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673337/bash-expand-parameters-from-variable-how

Comment: Are you perfectly sure that the shell you use in shebang (#!) can do that? Is it `/bin/bash` or is it `/bin/sh` pointing to `/bin/dash` in Debian or Ubuntu? If not change it to `/bin/bash` and try again.

Comment: The easiest way to figure out what to put after the shebang is to use the `which bash` command.  It will return the exact string you want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change shebang to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to run the script with bash as it supports brace expansion.

The problem is that you are using shell that does not support it. Your `/bin/sh` does not point to `/bin/bash` but to something like `/bin/dash`.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.7B

Comment: I realise this after running into an error with string manipulation too. Although I had #!/bin/bash as my shebang I was stupidly executing my script with sudo sh script

Answer (score -3):

You can try to use [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) for this.

```
sudo apt install tree
tree -d .
```

It's a great tool printing console-like tree directory structure:

```
├── logstash   
│   ├── afolder
│   ├── bfolder  
│   └── mappings  
├── elastic 
│   └── afolder  
└── reports  
    └── afolder
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/359723/mac-os-x-equivalent-of-the-ubuntu-tree-command

Comment: The question I believe was to make a nested directory structure of sorts from a single command/bash script. Tree however, gives a visual of the existing directory structure and does not really make one.